# WPF imagesource and upgrade image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resize, upgrade

My program loads an image and transform its colour, etc., with this operation:

```
FormatConvertedBitmap newformatedimage2 = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
newformatedimage2.BeginInit();

newformatedimage2.Source = cut.cut_image(newformatedimage, output_punti[0], output_punti[1], output_punti[4], output_punti[3]);
newformatedimage2.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.BlackWhite;
newformatedimage2.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Gray8;
newformatedimage2.EndInit();
```

after resizing the image with this operation

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();

bi.UriSource = new Uri("new_bar.bmp", UriKind.Relative);
bi.DecodePixelWidth = 1353;
bi.DecodePixelHeight = 2098;
bi.CacheOption=   BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

bi.EndInit();
```

`new_bar.bmp` is the image cut.
later calculate different operation in bi image

but this is the problem, after I load the new Image

`bi.urisource` is forever the first image and not the new image.

Is it possible to clean the cache for the new image?

Comment: I don't see you assigning that to a UI control anywhere...